# Designing Laravel Cache(Redis) Architecture

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5, redis

I'm designing a caching architecture for my api and I'm having issues with laravel relationships. This is how my current solution works:

My goal is to cache the whole response instead of caching individual models so I'm using Laravel's named routes for my cache names with the combination of actual url. For example:

> http://api.site.com/posts/1?with=author&status=1

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts','as' => 'Posts::'], function () {
   Route::get('/{id}', 'PostController@find')->name('find')->middleware('check_cache');
});
```

will be stored in Redis as `Api::Posts::find::http://api.site.com/posts/1?with=author&status=1`
This gives me the ability to flush my caches on different levels using Redis wildcards (*). This works well except when there are Laravel relationships in the response. For example, if I update an Author in my case, the Post cache should also be updated because of the dependency of Post on Author. I can't find a clean way to do this.

Is there any good solution to this? or is it a bad idea to cache the whole response and should I just switch to caching models. I really don't like the level of complexity that repository pattern adds to the project.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I see it you have 2 questions:

**1. Should you use caching for such requests?**

Well, it depends on the use case.

Typically you would use cache for frequent queries (when you need to perform a particular read op frequently but write not as frequently). If this isn't the case, you would generally fallback to DB.

The issue arises when you shoot for the opposite case - you start caching infrequent queries. That takes a toll on your app and DB is generally the best way to do this.

> So, for instance, in your case it might make sense just to cache the
>   most popular / frequently accessed posts and fallback to the database for the rest.

**2. How to cache stuff with relationships?**

Use [cache tags](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#cache-tags) in Laravel. Just tag your cached posts and cached authors with the same tag (say posts.postid.authorid) and then you can flush the tag like so: `Cache::tags('tagname')->flush();`

Comment: Thanks for the response but relationships are not always 1 value. For example 1 Post can have 200 comments. Does this mean I have to create a name like Post.1.2...200?

Comment: Well it has to be a common tag, e.g. you might choose to have Post.post_id for both comments and posts as the tag. If anything changes, flush the tag and both comments and posts would be "uncached". Of course, caching comments might not really be a good solution unless they're accessed frequently